# SSL without SslStream because I'd like to connect through a SOCKS5 Proxy

Tags: c#, encryption, ssl, socks

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION:**  PROGRAM WRITTEN IN C#

I'm working on a program right now that connects through a SOCKS5 proxy (coded from scratch. works well enough.), but I'd also like to (through that proxy) communicate to a DESTINATION through SSL.

I've done some research, googled many a time, and have come to the conclusion that SslStream won't be ideal for my situation.  I NEED to first authenticate with the SSL through the proxy, and THEN start sending encrypted packets, once I receive the key.

**QUESTIONS:**

How can I encrypt my packets with TLS in C#?  For some reason I can't at all figure it out.  I'm stuck! :(

What is the raw syntax required to even REQUEST said SSL certificate?

Comment: With the question as it is now, you're going to get more questions than answers.

Comment: Well, thanks for the input.  I'd like to actually start SOMEWHERE, so if someone could say something DIFFERENT than what that guy Fantius said, I'd be 10 steps ahead of where I am now.  Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you go from the client to the proxy in plaintext and from the proxy to the server using SSL?  Obviously that means code changes to the proxy.

Comment: Also, what are you authenticating against?  The server at the end?  "authenticate with the SSL" makes no sense.  What makes you think you need to authenticate before entering SSL mode?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to https via socks5 proxy.  I can't use sslstream, according to my research.  I AM communicating to the proxy server via plain text.  My goal is to be able to go through a socks 5 proxy and THEN connect to the SSL.  I'm also asking how to encrypt the packets once I get the key from the certificate.   Thank you for the follow-up.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the TLS implementation in the open source [Bouncy Castle cryptography library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).  If it won't work as-is, you can hack it into doing what you need.  If you want to deep-dive the specification itself, you'll find it as [IETF RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246).

As you've probably discovered, though, doing any portion of the connection setup work yourself leaves you with no way to use the `WebRequest` family of classes to handle the HTTP portion of the protocol work.  That leaves you with two options I can see: do the HTTP yourself as well (I found a [trivial example HTTP client](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/71499d78-181c-44f0-a5e5-14b26786913f.aspx) floating around the net), or change the current user proxy server settings

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyServer"="socks=socks.example.net:1080"
```

then send the request normally using the `WebRequest` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer you [SSLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product. Among numerous other components it has a simple SSL client component that is socket-based, can connect via different proxies (SOCKS, HTTPS CONNECT) and supports all features of SSL/TLS up to TLS 1.2. If you need more control, you can use any custom socket, and not just built-in socket support. This lets you use the components for securing traffic that goes not via sockets at all (pigeon mail can be secured this way as well).

An HTTPS client is available and included into SSLBlackbox as well.